# ImagickException, Failed to read the file. PHP

Tags: php

estoy trabajando con Imagick.
El proceso que hago es:

1. Descarga archivos (PDF) del FTP y genero temporales en el servidor.
2. Una vez que los tengo en el servidor, paso a contar las hojas de cada PDF iterando los temporales:

> ```
> $cantpaginasTemporales = 0;
> foreach ($archivos as $clave => $valor){
>   $nombrelcalarchivo = $path . $nombrelocal . $clave . '.pdf';
>   $cantpaginasTemporales = $cantpaginasTemporales + $pdfGest->countPage($nombrelcalarchivo);
> }
> ```

Los temporales se generan OK en el servidor.

El error no sucede siempre. Por ejemplo, intente 3 veces de ejecutar el codigo y fallo en la tercera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error en la linea 330 es la siguiente (en la instancia Imagick):

```
public function countPage($pathFile) {
    ob_start(); 
    $im = new Imagick($pathFile);       
    $noOfPagesInPDF = $im->getNumberImages(); 
    ob_end_flush();         
     return $noOfPagesInPDF;
 }
```

Me llama la atención, por que aveces funciona OK y aveces no.
NO estoy utilizando GS

Comment: Revisa la ruta del archivo y que lo hayas transferido en modo binario, en la imagen no se alcanza a ver el error completo (con la ruta). Independientemente de eso, no necesitas búfer de salida y en este caso es decente llamar `$im->clear()`.

Comment: entra por el navegador a la ruta donde se supone esta el pdf y comprueba que realmente existe.